# How to invert the coordinates of a point relative to another point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The coordinates of the red points are known.
Find the coordinates of the green point.

[image]

Comment: subtract the coordinates of the middle red point from the one of the other red point, then inverse all coordinates of the result, then add the coordinates of the middle red point again

Comment: Is distance the same between red points and middle red and green?

Comment: @Johnny, distance between red dots equal distance between green and red (center) dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (without using a standard library function that I don't know of) is probably to do this: (assuming Red1 is the middle red dot, Red2 is the upper right red dot and both are of type `UnityEngine.Vector2`)

```
Vector2 greenDot = (Vector2.zero - (Red2 - Red1)) + Red1;
```

Comment: Perfect! I use vector3. But it works correctly! Thanks!